# Problem in my program code of c please help me in resolving the problem

Tags: c

WHY I AM getting ERROR during COMPILATION with GCC even i have putted the `ch` variable as `char` type?

my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void circular(int*,int*,int*);

int main(){


    int n1,n2,n3,flag=1;

    char fb='y';

    do{

        printf("enter the value of x,y,z resp.: ");

        scanf("%d%d%d",&n1,&n2,&n3);

        circular(&n1,&n2,&n3);

        printf("after %d circular shift values are: \nx= %d\ny= %d\nz= %d\nwant to do circular shift again(y/n): ",flag,n1,n2,n3);

        scanf("%s",fb);

        flag+=1;

    }while(fb=='y' || fb=='Y');


    return 0;


}

void circular(int *n1,int *n2,int *n3){

    int temp;

    temp=*n1;

    *n1=*n2;

    *n2=*n3;

    *n3=temp;


}
```

error after compiling with gcc:

```
c4q13.c: In function ‘main’:
c4q13.c:22:11: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   22 |   scanf("%s",fb);
      |          ~^  ~~
      |           |  |
      |           |  int
      |           char *
```

Comment: What is "the `ch` variable"?

Comment: `char` is in no way the same as `char *`. Try `char fb[2]; scanf("%s",fb);` But note that this is very unsafe code as it will overflow the buffer if the user enters more than one character.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, the variable `fb` has type `char` and it is promoted to `int` in variable-number arguments. You have to pass `char*` for `%s` in `scanf()`.

Also `%s` reads *strings* (sequence of characters *terminated by a null-character*), so passing a pointer to an one-character buffer for `%s` is bad, causing dangerous out-of-range access.

You should allocate an array for string and pass a pointer to its element. Also you should set the maximum number of characters to read to avoid buffer overrun. Considering the terminating null-character, the limit should be (at most) the number of elements in the buffer minus one.

Things to change:

```
    char fb='y';
        scanf("%s",fb);
    }while(fb=='y' || fb=='Y');
```

They should be:

```
    char fb[4]="y";
        scanf("%3s",fb);
    }while(fb[0]=='y' || fb[0]=='Y');
```